# Application won't load in heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku

The Ruby on Rails application I have been working on for a tutorial doesn't work. I have done the same pushing through Git procedure before, it was working. Now it shows the following error, what am I doing wrong?

```
-----> Ruby/Rails app detected
-----> Using Ruby version: ruby-2.0.0
-----> Installing dependencies using 
Running: bundle install --without development:test --path vendor/bundle --binstubs vendor/bundle/bin --deployment
/usr/bin/env: ruby1.9.1: No such file or directory
Bundler Output: /usr/bin/env: ruby1.9.1: No such file or directory
!
!     Failed to install gems via Bundler.
!
!     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby/Rails app

To git@heroku.com:aqueous-savannah-3944.git
! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@heroku.com:aqueous-savannah-3944.git'
```

Here is the GemFile of the app

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails'

group :development do
gem 'sqlite3'
gem 'rspec-rails'
end

group :test do
gem 'capybara'
end
# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
gem 'sass-rails'   
gem 'coffee-rails' 

gem 'uglifier'
end

gem 'jquery-rails' 
gem 'turbolinks'

group :production do
gem 'pg'
end
```

Comment: What is your local version of Ruby for this project?

Comment: ruby 1.9.3p194 (2012-04-20 revision 35410) [x86_64-linux]

Answer (score 1):

This is probably caused by problems with your PATH. Try the following:

```
heroku run "ruby -v"
```

You should get something about your ruby version. If there's a problem, use this command:

```
heroku config -s | grep PATH
```

If `bin` isn't in your path, you should be able to use:

```
heroku config:set PATH=/bin:$PATH
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: heroku config -s | grep PATH
doesn't return anything

Comment: Hmm, strange. How about deleting the lock (`rm Gemfile.lock`) and running `bundle install` again? Maybe `bundle update` can do the job.

Answer (score 0):

Set Ruby version in Gemfie and try again

```
ruby "1.9.3"
```

Comment: i tried that. The problem is when i push this to git it won't change the Gemfile in the git repo. So when I push it to heroku too it won't work. Getting really tired of this

Comment: Wait, you did above, you did `bundle install` added, commited, pushed and still not working?

Comment: i tried. 1. bundle install, 2. git add . , 3. git commit -m "message" 4.git push origin master, 3. git push heroku master

Comment: Could you paste full log from heroku on git push? This looks strange, like heroku bug...

Comment: ah, and check `heroku config` for path! @agarie

Comment: heroku config
aqueous-savannah-3944 has no config vars.

Comment: You have a cedar stack app (url is .herokuapp.com)?

Comment: Can you also try and create a new app?

Comment: yeah i have a cedar stack app

Comment: @Aravind - I am confused about your first comment.  If you change the text in a Gemfile to read ruby "1.9.3", then save the file, you should be able to git add / git commit the Gemfile to your local git repository and then git push it up to heroku.  Your first comment suggests you cant do this.

Comment: @jr0cket It was a small mistake i was doing working in a different branch. I solved that, now even after the changes in the remote git repo Heroku still won't take the app